# Making boost::fast_pool_allocator work with variadic templates (emplace)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm trying to use `boost::fast_pool_allocator` as the allocator for a `std::list`, but it fails to find the [overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct) for `construct()` that uses variadic templates.

```
#include <list>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef std::pair<int, int> Pair;
    std::list<Pair, boost::fast_pool_allocator<Pair>> list;

    list.emplace(list.begin(), 1, 2);
}
```

This fails to compile with the following error (shortened):

```
stl_list.h:514:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::fast_pool_allocator<blah>::construct(std::list<bleh>::_Node*&, int, int)'
```

Looking at the [header file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/fast_pool_allocator.html), it seems `boost::fast_pool_allocator` only has the pre-C++11 version of `construct()` (a pointer and a const_reference).

Note that defining the list as `std::list<Pair>` (i.e. using the default allocator) works fine.

Is there a workaround for this? Any adaptor or some way of defining the allocator traits? I'm new to allocators so this is kind of a dark land for me.

I can make it work with

```
list.emplace(list.begin(), Pair(1, 2));
```

but 1st) the actual class I'm using in production is much more complex than the `Pair` I used for the example and performance is paramount (so I could really use in-place construction), and 2nd) ideally, I'd like to have a drop-in replacement for `std::allocator`, so I could measure the performance difference with a one-line change.

I'm compiling in Cygwin with g++ 4.9.2 and boost 1.58.0, and I have the same problem in a linux environment (RHEL5.5) with g++ 4.8.3 and boost 1.55.0.

Comment: As a thought, write `my_fpa<T>` that inherits from `fpa<T>` with new functionality?  Or that has-a `fpa<T>` and forwards?  Make sure you get `rebind` right if you inherit.

Comment: Already did something very similar, but with no inheritance. It still only works if I default to using the pre-C++11 `construct` directive, so no chance of using `emplace`, which is what I want.

Comment: And when you wrote a C++11 style `construct` in your derived version what exactly went wrong?

Comment: It's not exactly a derived version, but a wrapper around `boost::fast_pool_allocator` that only allows to allocate 1 chunk at a time. I'll give a try to the suggestion in your answer.

Comment: This actually looks like a libstdc++ bug specific to `std::list`. Their `vector` behaves properly.

Comment: OK, they document that their `std::list` has ["incomplete allocator support"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T,
  typename UserAllocator,
  typename Mutex,
  unsigned NextSize,
  unsigned MaxSize >
struct my_pool_allocator:
  boost::pool_allocator<T,UserAllocator,Mutex,NextSize,MaxSize>
{
  using base=boost::pool_allocator<T,UserAllocator,Mutex,NextSize,MaxSize>;
  using base::base;
  template <typename U>
  struct rebind
  {
    using other=my_pool_allocator<U, UserAllocator, Mutex, NextSize, MaxSize>;
  };
  using base::construct;
  template<class...Args>
  void construct(const typename base::pointer ptr, Args&&...args)
  { new (ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};
```

or somesuch.  Inherit from `fast_pool_allocator`, inherit its constructors, write a custom `rebind`, inherit `construct`, and add another overload of `construct` that handles varargs.

One should be able to write a "modernize allocator" template that does most of this for you I suspect.

```
template <class OldAllocator>
struct modernize_allocator:
  OldAllocator
{
  using base=OldAllocator;

  using T=typename base::value_type;

  using base::base;
  template <typename U>
  struct rebind
  {
    using other=modernize_allocator<typename base::rebind<U>::other>;
  };

  using base::construct;
  template<class...Args>
  void construct(const typename base::pointer ptr, Args&&...args)
  { new (ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};
```

There may be typos/errors above: it is just a sketch of a solution.

Comment: Thanks Yakk, this seems to work. I hope it pays off performance-wise.

Comment: Minor nitpick: I believe `construct` is supposed to operate on a raw pointer, not the possibly fancy `base::pointer`.

Comment: @T.C. Possibly: but I took the signature of `pool_allocator::construct` and extended it for varargs.  Possibly `pool_allocator::construct` has a problem there?  Or maybe `pool_allocator::construct` "knows" its `pointer` is a raw pointer?

Comment: @Yakk I guess it's the latter. Hmm, C++03 actually uses `pointer` there - but then it also allows implementations to assume that `pointer` is a raw pointer.

Comment: Now I'm starting to wonder if you can (ab)use `scoped_allocator_adaptor` for "modernization" purposes... (Edit: [it seems to work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29bd7088ca2d74c4))

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, it should be possible to use `fast_pool_allocator` directly with a C++11-conforming container, since the container is supposed to use `allocator_traits::construct`, which in turn calls the `allocator`'s `construct` only if the call is well-formed ([allocator.traits.members]/p5):

> ```
> template <class T, class... Args>
> static void construct(Alloc& a, T* p, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: calls `a.construct(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...)` if that call is well-formed; otherwise, invokes `::new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`.

The problem is that libstdc++'s `std::list` [is still not conforming to the C++11 standard](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html); it directly calls `construct` on the allocator. As a workaround, Yakk's answer is good.

Comment: that would still mean that move-construction would devolve to a copy-construct, as `const pointer, T const&` signature of a C++03 allocator's `construct` method will bind to the `const pointer, T&&` arguments of a move-construct.  In fact, any non-explicit single-argument conversion will turn into creating a temporary, then copying that temporary, then discarding that temporary it isn't already a temporary or lvalue of type `T`.

Comment: @Yakk Good point. For C++11 it's probably simpler to just remove the `construct` entirely - but then libstdc++'s `std::list` will still break. Oops.